# Why can this conversion between two interfaces work when there seems no inheritance relation between the interfaces?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand some code written by others. Because I am not allowed to post the original code which is also complicated, I have to simplify it

```
IAData a = SomeProperty;
IBData b = a as IBData;
BData ret = b.B;
```

where `IAData` and `IBData` are two interfaces:

```
public interface IBData
{
    BData B { get; set; }
}

public interface IAData
{
    void Clear();
}
```

and

```
private IAData _aData;
public IAData SomeProperty { get { return _aData; } }
```

Why can `a` be explicitly converted to `b`, given that there seems no inheritance relation between `IAData` and `IBData`?

Do I miss something? Apologize if I simplify the code too much.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that `b` is not `null`?

Comment: I ain't no C# guy but isn't this possible if a particular class implements both interfaces and your object is an instance of such a class? (Cf. `dynamic_cast` of C++).

Comment: I think that if there's no explicit conversion between `IAData` and `IBData` `b` sould be null. Though I don't know how to define explicit conversion between interfaces.

Comment: This is not an explicit conversion. Look at the [MSDN for the as operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) "*The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.*"

Answer (score 6):

A class can implement multiple interfaces

```
interface IA { }
interface IB { }
class C : IA, IB { }
```

In such case a cast from one interface to the other is valid

```
IA a = new C();
IB b = a as IB;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it a good practice, given the confusion which I and possibly other readers had?

Comment: @Tim it would not be good practice to assume that because something implements `IAData` it will also implement `IBData` no. Unless it's the case that `IAData` inherits from `IBData`. But there is nothing wrong with a class implementing multiple interfaces. And in a case where you think a class that implements `IAData` might implement `IBData` it would be fine to use either `as` (with a null check) or `is` to see if it does. But you should have logic to handle the case where it doesn't.

Comment: @Tim I would not call it a good practice. Very often in case of such casts an explicit inheritance will make sense and will make the code clearer. An example I can think of when it would be fine to cast between unrelated interfaces is working with an interface you cannot modify and checking if the referenced object also implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 4):

`IAData a = SomeProperty` makes `IAData` the *static* type of `a`. However, the *dynamic* type of `a` is some class that implements `IAData`, and maybe some other interfaces. The compiler may or may not know if `IBData` is among these interfaces.

If `IBData` happens to be among the interfaces implemented by the class of the object from `SomeProperty`, then the cast is going to succeed, and `b` would be non-null. Otherwise, `b` would be `null`, which is something the code needs to test.

Although the compiler can run a check and see if any class implementing `IAData` also implements `IBData` and trigger an error if the cast has no chance of being successful, this check would be impractical, because another implementation can be added at a later time. That is why the compiler does not report an error or a warning; that is also why a `null` check or `null` propagation should be used with the result of `as` operator.

Answer (score 3):

A class can implement both interfaces, and the `as` operator will return it converted to the desired interface, or `null` if the concrete class doesn't implement it.